# When will I get attacked in Clash of Clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just started playing clash of clans. Aside from the first attack by goblins in the tutorial I haven't been attacked. When do I need to worry about my defenses? Right now I'm content to just farm away and build up. If I never use the attack function will I also never get attacked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can be attacked at any time where your shield is not active.

If you look at the top of the screen you will see an information label that says "Shield".  At any time that this says "None" you can be attacked by other players (excluding times where you are actively playing - i.e. the game is open on your device).

When you first start the game you are given a free shield for several days to give you time to build your defences up.  Your shield can later be reactivated:

- At any time for a set fee of gems (1 day, 2 day and 1 week options)
- If you are attacked by another player and lose 40% of buildings or town hall the shield is reactivated for 12 hours (war attacks do not count)
- If you are attacked by another player and lose 90% of buildings the shield is reactivated for 16 hours (war attacks do not count)

Attacking another player *in multiplayer* disables any shield you have.

You can also never be attacked whilst you have the app open.

Comment: You also cannot be attacked when you are online in the game, regardless of your shield status. This is helpful if you're shield-less, a builder is about to free up, and you're sitting on a massive pile of resources devoted to a major upgrade. Keep the device/game from going idle and you'll be protected from attacks.

Comment: If you have a shield, it is also wise to not attack, as each attack will remove 3 hours from your active shield. The shield is not effected attacking the goblin villages in single-player.

Answer (score 2):

You will get attacked no matter what in the game. The only time the goblins attack is in the tutorial. Other players will attack you after a while though, even if you don't attack since you need internet connection to play the game. You should worry about defences since they protect your village and more importantly your resources, since your buildings are not actually destroyed when someone attacks you.

Answer (score 2):

With two separate accounts, I never used the attack function.  Both of those accounts were raided two or three times until I won a defense (someone was dropping trophies).  That one successful defense granted me 20 trophies, and I was never attacked again until reaching TH5 several months later.

As an experiment, I tried it again with a third account upgrading nothing but gold mines, elixir collectors, storage units, and town hall (zero defenses). Same as before, I won one defense, gained 20 trophies, and the attacks just stopped.  Since I wasn't buying anything else, it took just over two weeks to get to TH5 with maxed out resource collectors, and then the attacks started coming.  One guy attacked with three goblins, lost intentionally, my trophies jumped to 47, and the attacks became continual.  I've tried dropping back to 20, but people simply revenge attack and lose intentionally.  That said, I still don't lose many resources because most people with trophy counts this low have no intention of winning, just dropping trophies.

I'm convinced that you are safe until your trophy count rises above 20 (with the first 20 coming from a successful defense, NOT a successful raid) or you reach TH5.

Answer (score 0):

You can get attacked at any point in the game when you are not in the tutorial. However, you are more likely to be raided if you have more loot or if you have a bad defense.

Answer (score -2):

You have a shield for 72hours when you first start the game so you cannot get attacked until that has run out.